# How to find out sub soil moisture from Satellite Images?

Tags: geospatial

Want to find out sub soil moisture from Sentinel or any other satellite images. But don't know the process exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested into some global soil moisture products, I'd advice to see what is doing the research group lead by Wolfgang Wagner in TUWien, which is a world-leading research group in soil moisture products from remote sensing. This [page](http://rs.geo.tuwien.ac.at/data-viewers/) is a gateway for 3 different products:

- Metop ASCAT Soil Moisture
- ESA CCI Soil Moisture

The ESA-CCI soil moisture product (daily global soil moisture data) can be downloaded from this [page](http://www.esa-soilmoisture-cci.org/node/145) after completing a form.

- ASAR 1km Surface Soil Moisture

If you want to know how soil moisture can be retrieved from remote sensing, it is actually a quite long process and it depends a lot of what you are interested in (passive vs active sensors, time & spatial resolution, depth of characterization). I'd suggest the following review article, although many other are available:

- Wagner, W., Blöschl, G., Pampaloni, P., Calvet, J. C., Bizzarri, B., Wigneron, J. P., & Kerr, Y. (2007). Operational readiness of microwave remote sensing of soil moisture for hydrologic applications. Hydrology Research, 38(1), 1-20.

Note: I'm not involved at all in the Wagner research group. Other research group worldwide and publications are surely worth considering.